# Is it possible to set request authorization in 'serverless.yml' file with Serverless 1.0.0-beta.1.1?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I just tried version .1.0.0-beta.1.1 of [Serverless](http://serverless.com/), which looks very promising.

I wish to authentify requests, using `AWS_IAM`.

I can use the AWS Gateway API console, and change each method request from `none` to `AWS_IAM`. By hand, I can make it work.

However, I would rather change the `serverless.yml` file in my Serverless services.

I tried to add an `authorizationType` field like so:

```
- http:
      path: greet
      method: get
      authorizationType: AWS_IAM
```

but it did not update the authorization settings of API Gateway, and unauthorized requests are still accepted.

---

Any idea if the `serverless.yml` file can be set to use `AWS_IAM`?

Answer (score 2):

In serverless 1.0.0-RC2 you can set the authorizationType as follows

```
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
          path: hello
          method: get    

resources:
  Resources:
    ApiGatewayMethodHelloGet:
      Properties:
        AuthorizationType: AWS_IAM
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the following link for the closest I found on help with authentication:

https://github.com/serverless/serverless/blob/85f4084e6b0fd4a6d763ace8cd0db82817bbc712/lib/plugins/aws/deploy/compile/events/apiGateway/README.md#http-setup-with-custom-authorizer

I have not used AWS_IAM, but here is how I define a CUSTOM authentication, which should indicate the overall format.

```
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
          path: hello
          method: get
          authorizer:
            arn: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxxxxx:function:jwtAuthorize
            resultTtlInSeconds: 0
            identitySource: method.request.header.Authorization
            identityValidationExpression: JWT [^\.]+\.[^\.]+\.[^\.]+
```

Therefore, I think you need to add the `authorizer` section. I cannot test this, but let me know if it does not work this way:

```
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
          path: hello
          method: get
          authorizer:
            authorizationType: AWS_IAM
```

Comment: authorizationType: AWS_IAM certainly does not work.
ServerlessError: Please provide either an authorizer name or ARN